# Should we only use American English for tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the tags [dialog](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialog) and [dialogue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue). Probably we have or get other tags which show the subtleties between British and American English. Even so I am in favour (<- see!) of the British variant, the American spelling is used on the SOFU sites. We should choose one and keep it and I suggest American English.

Answer (score 3):

In general the guidance here is "we don't really care, but pick one and stick with it consistently."

As you pointed out, much of the rest of the networks' tags are American English so that seems like a sensible tag default.